# Perl OOP method condition $self->{$tag}

Tags: perl

I am learning about the perl and reviewing some old codes of OOP.
In the pl, there is one line call the function in the pm file.
like

```
my $id = new ABC::Data::InstallData();
my $startMenu = $id->getData('menu');
```

In the pm file, the functions is like below:

```
package ABC::Data::InstallData;

$debug = 1;
sub getData {                            
    my($self, $tag) = @_;                   
    #print "----1------$self-----------\n";
    #print "----2------$tag-----------\n";

    if ( $debug && ! defined $self->{$tag} ) {
       $logger->debug("Undefined variable $tag = $self->{$tag}");     
    }

    if ( $debug ) {
       $logger->debug("Exiting ABC::Data::InstallData::getData");     
    }
    return $self->{$tag};                                              
}
```

As you can see, there are 2 lines print that can output the Class name and the parameter inputed.
But I do  not understand `$self->{$tag}` meaning, can someone helps?

Comment: What part don't you understand? `$self` is the object, and the key that corresponds to `$tag` is a property of the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$self->{tag}
```

...in this case is a Class Attribute. This appears to be a setter/getter method within a class. Here's an example of this in action (verbose):

```
sub new {
    my ($class, $arg) = @_;
    my $self = bless {}, $class;
    $self->arg($arg);
    return $self;
}
sub arg {
    my ($self, $arg) = @_;
    if (defined $arg){
        $self->{arg} = $arg;
    }
    return $self->{arg};
}
```

Then, when I use that module:

```
my $object = Blah->new(2);
print $object->arg;

# you can even access object attributes outside of the
# documented accessor methods, but it breaks encapsulation, 
# so you just don't do it

print $object->{arg};
```

Output:

```
2
```

In essence, the subroutine `getData()` returns the value of `$self->{tag}`, where `$self` is an object of the class (and is a hash reference), and `tag` is an attribute of that object (stuffed into the blessed hash reference `$self` (the object)). When you call it with a parameter, `$self->{tag}` is set, then returned, and called without a parameter, no setting of the attribute is done, and the previous (current) value is returned.